# Getting metadata about a SQL query (eg total data scanned) from JDBC connection?

Tags: sql, jdbc, teradata

I'm interested in getting query-specific metadata data from a JDBC connection with a Teradata DB.

After a query, I can interrogate the cursor for `ResultSetMetadata`, which gives me information about the `ResultSet` itself (column names and types, column properties, etc), but won't tell me anything about what the query did.

The closest thing I can think to do is to execute a second query, prepending the main one with `EXPLAIN`, and then parsing the result of this explanation to get *estimates* (not real data) for spool usage and time costs.

Is there any way to specify that I want a query's use of resources to be tracked?

Comment: @philipxy I explicitly mention `ResultSetMetadata` and how it doesn't seem to contain the information I'm looking for.

Comment: https://www.dwhpro.com/query-stats-teradata/ ?

Comment: A query's estimated & actual resource usage (and much more) is recorded in the DBQL. Talk to your DBA if you have/can get access to it. But it's cashed, thus there is a delay (seconds to few minutes) before it's available.

Comment: @dnoeth interestingly, `DBQLogTbl` and `DBQLSQLTbl` are both empty, despite a few queries having been run on this DB instance. Do you know of a setting that needs to be turned on to get these metrics stored?

Comment: @ap: If they're empty DBQL is not enabled on your system. That's very strange, every system should have DBQL switched on. Ask your DBA about that.

Comment: @dnoeth I don't really have a DBA to ask, unfortunately. I'll see what google says.

Comment: @ap: If you can switch on DBQL & don't have a DBA you *are* either the DBA or you run an Express version :-)

Comment: @dnoeth It'd be a stretch to call me a DBA, but I guess that's the hat I'm wearing for now... thanks for the help. Feel free to put in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ap:  Your existing answer is correct, no need to add another one :-)

Comment: There is no such thing in JDBC itself, but sometimes drivers have database-specific extensions for such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who's interested in this, the answer is that no, this cannot be done through the same connection.

The approach I'll end up taking is probably to [enable query logging](http://databasebestpractices.com/setup-dbql-database-query-logging-teradata/)

```
begin query logging with objects, sql, usecount, utilityinfo LIMIT SQLTEXT=0 on all;
begin query logging with objects, sql limit threshold = 5 elapsedsec and sqltext=0 on VIEWPOINT;
```

and then querying `DBC.DBQLogTbl` and `DBC.DBQLSQLTbl` using something like what's outlined in [this forum post](https://community.teradata.com/t5/General/Need-Help-with-DBQL-query-to-find-top-10-queries-with-high-cpu/td-p/43644), either streamed if possible or simply batch queried semi regularly to get 'real time-ish' metrics.

```
select  top 50
  ProcID
, QueryID
, AMPCPUTime
, MaxAMPCPUTime * (hashamp () + 1) CPUImpact
, CAST (100 - ((AmpCPUTime / (hashamp () + 1)) * 100 / NULLIFZERO (MaxAMPCPUTime)) AS INTEGER) "CPUSkew%"
, TotalIOCount
, MaxAMPIO * (hashamp () + 1) IOImpact
, CAST (100 - ((TotalIOCount / (hashamp () + 1)) * 100 / NULLIFZERO (MaxAMPIO) ) AS INTEGER) "IOSkew%"
, AMPCPUTime * 1000 / nullifzero (TotalIOCount) LHR
, TotalIOCount / nullifzero (AMPCPUTime * 1000) RHL
, ParserCPUTime
, Queryband
, Substr(QueryText,1,2000) QueryText
from
/* For archived DBQL
    dbql_arch.dbqlogtbl_hst where logdate=1131201
 and ampcputime>0
*/
/* For online DBQL*/
    dbc.dbqlogtbl where
    cast(cast(starttime as char(10)) as date) = '2013-12-18' (date)
    and ampcputime>0
order by CPUImpact desc;
```

Comment: But don't forget to do some housekeeping, DBQL tends to grow quite fast. And any history should be moved daily outside of `dbc` into tables with better Primary Indexes (fast read vs. fast write).

Comment: Good point. In my case, the data will be retrieved once per query and immediately deleted. Others will not have such luxury, I suppose :)